# How to get TF-IDF scores for the words?

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have a large corpus (around 400k unique sentences). I just want to get TF-IDF score for each word. I tried to calculate the score for each word by scanning each word and calculating the frequency but it's taking too long.

I used :

```
  X= tfidfVectorizer(corpus)
```

from sklearn but it directly gives back the vector representation of the sentence. Is there any way I can get the TF-IDF scores for each word in the corpus?

Comment: TF-IDF is not per word across the whole corpus, it is per word per document, so  you can't get a value per unique word in the corpus. Also, can you show exactly how you used `TfidfVectorizer`?

Comment: That is exactly I needed. Score per word per document/corpus. @Tomothy32

Comment: Again, can you show exactly how you used `TfidfVectorizer`?

Comment: Its the same way I commented above . corpus = list(sentences in the document). But it returns the unique vector representation for each sentence. But, you don't know the exact scores of each word against the document.

Comment: Use `vectorizer.get_feature_names()` and `vectorizer.idf_` to get the score for each word.  Refer [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar OP wants TF-IDF, not just IDF

Answer (score 29):

To use [`sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) (taken from the docs):

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This document is the second document.',
...     'And this is the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
>>> print(X.shape)
(4, 9)
```

Now, if I print `X.toarray()`:

```
[[0.         0.46979139 0.58028582 0.38408524 0.         0.
  0.38408524 0.         0.38408524]
 [0.         0.6876236  0.         0.28108867 0.         0.53864762
  0.28108867 0.         0.28108867]
 [0.51184851 0.         0.         0.26710379 0.51184851 0.
  0.26710379 0.51184851 0.26710379]
 [0.         0.46979139 0.58028582 0.38408524 0.         0.
  0.38408524 0.         0.38408524]]
```

Each row in this 2D array refers to a document, and each element in the row refers to the TF-IDF score of the corresponding word. To know what word each element is representing, look at the `.get_feature_names()` function. It will print out a list of words. For example, in this case, look at the row for the first document:

```
[0., 0.46979139, 0.58028582, 0.38408524, 0., 0., 0.38408524, 0., 0.38408524]
```

In the example, `.get_feature_names()` returns this:

```
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
```

Therefore, you map the scores to the words like this:

```
dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), X.toarray()[0]))
{'and': 0.0, 'document': 0.46979139, 'first': 0.58028582, 'is': 0.38408524, 'one': 0.0, 'second': 0.0, 'the': 0.38408524, 'third': 0.0, 'this': 0.38408524}
```

Comment: this is wrong. In your last code snippet, why are you mapping a vector of the first sentence in the corpus to the `vectorizer.get_feature_names()` ? The latter simply returns all unique tokens used to build a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter noted, the given answer is wrong. The below method gets a sum of the sparse array per token.

```
# initialise vectoriser
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
# apply to corpus of documents
X = tfidf.fit_transform(docs)  
# map feature names to sum of vector array
tfidf_dict = dict(zip(tfidf.get_feature_names_out(), X.toarray().sum(axis=0)))
# sort in descending order
tfidf_dict = dict(sorted(tfidf_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
```

Then, you can optionally display that as a pandas dataframe...

```
# initialise dataframe
tfidf_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tfidf_dict, orient='index', columns=['tfidf'])
# name the index
tfidf_df.index = tfidf_df.index.rename('token')
# display first 5 rows
tfidf_df.head()
```